# How can I create multiple jars from the same source but different main class for each jar?

Tags: java, gradle

Here is what my build.gradle looks like. I want to be able to create multiple jars from the same project but different main class for each jar?
The linkToBin function in the end will be the last function to be executed and it should collect all the jars by doing `configurations.testRuntime.allArtifacts.files.forEach`. Anyways the big question is how can I create multiple jars from the same source but different main class for each jar? any help would be great

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group 'com.hello'
version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs '/usr/local/hello/lib'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.3.1'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.12'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile "com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5"
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.6.2'
   compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.8.11.2'
   compile project(':anchor_service_api_thrift')
}

jar {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    from sourceSets.test.output
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.hello.echoserver.AnchorEchoServer'
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/.RSA', 'META-INF/.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}

task (anchorHttpServerJar, dependsOn: 'classes', type: Jar) {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    from sourceSets.test.output
    archivesBaseName = 'anchor_echo_http_server'
    version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    manifest {
        attributes ('Main-Class': 'com.hello.httpserver.AnchorHttpServer')
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/.RSA', 'META-INF/.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}

artifacts {
   archives anchorHttpServerJar
}

build.dependsOn(linkToBin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

In your **build.gradle** file, simply add the following:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "you.main.class.Program"
```

Comment: In my case I am trying to produce two jars with different main classes within the same project right. so what would that be?

Comment: You can run 'gradle build' twice, while providing the main class name as a parameter.